# How to use Svg image with multiple paths

Tags: wpf, svg, pathgeometry

For a test, I used [InkScape](https://inkscape.org/) to create following `svg` file that correctly displays the the image `TEX` in all major browsers (IE, Chrome, Edge, FireFox etc.). Now I want to display this as an icon for a button on a `WPF` app. AS you may have noticed the `svg` file has multiple paths. I tried to used those multiple paths in WPF button as follows but it does not show the image `TEX`. **Question**: How do we use multiple `Paths` of an svg image in a `WPF` app. How the following svg file can be used to display an icon of a button in a `WPF` app?

**WPF Button** [does not display the svg icon]

```
<Button Width="36" Height="36" ToolTip="Test for svg image">
    <Viewbox>
       <Grid>
            <Path Data="M 65.210466,41.41868 H 62.80752 V 47.625 h -1.984369 v -6.20632 h -2.402946 v -1.488276 h 6.790261 z"/>
            <Path Data="m 71.969722,47.625 h -5.565534 v -7.694596 h 5.565534 v 1.488276 h -3.591501 v 1.32808 h 3.33312 v 1.488277 h -3.33312 v 1.901686 h 3.591501 z"/>
            <Path Data="M 80.609994,47.625 H 78.315568 L 76.65676,45.092863 74.966946,47.625 h -2.191074 l 2.728507,-3.87572 -2.671663,-3.818876 h 2.289258 l 1.601965,2.397779 1.648473,-2.397779 h 2.196241 l -2.687166,3.741362 z"/>
       </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
</Button>
```

**svg file**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="22.189789mm"
   height="7.6945963mm"
   viewBox="0 0 22.189789 7.6945963"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg45"
   inkscape:version="1.0.1 (3bc2e813f5, 2020-09-07)"
   sodipodi:docname="drawing-1_plain_Path.svg">
  <defs
     id="defs39" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="0.35"
     inkscape:cx="-307.94363"
     inkscape:cy="409.08194"
     inkscape:document-units="mm"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     inkscape:document-rotation="0"
     showgrid="false"
     fit-margin-top="0"
     fit-margin-left="0"
     fit-margin-right="0"
     fit-margin-bottom="0"
     inkscape:window-width="1366"
     inkscape:window-height="705"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata42">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(-58.420205,-39.930404)">
    <g
       aria-label="TEX"
       id="text49"
       style="font-weight:bold;font-size:10.5833px;line-height:1.25;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif Bold';stroke-width:0.264583"
       inkscape:export-xdpi="96"
       inkscape:export-ydpi="96">
      <path
         d="M 65.210466,41.41868 H 62.80752 V 47.625 h -1.984369 v -6.20632 h -2.402946 v -1.488276 h 6.790261 z"
         style="stroke-width:0.264583"
         id="path60" />
      <path
         d="m 71.969722,47.625 h -5.565534 v -7.694596 h 5.565534 v 1.488276 h -3.591501 v 1.32808 h 3.33312 v 1.488277 h -3.33312 v 1.901686 h 3.591501 z"
         style="stroke-width:0.264583"
         id="path62" />
      <path
         d="M 80.609994,47.625 H 78.315568 L 76.65676,45.092863 74.966946,47.625 h -2.191074 l 2.728507,-3.87572 -2.671663,-3.818876 h 2.289258 l 1.601965,2.397779 1.648473,-2.397779 h 2.196241 l -2.687166,3.741362 z"
         style="stroke-width:0.264583"
         id="path64" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Your paths have no fill, you got them all in a grid which would put em all in top of one another. You got no stretch or height and width set on em. I would try a geometrygroup with the three geometries in it as the data for one path. And don't ignore the above.

Comment: If this is one of several similar text to path requirements. Syncfusion metro studio allows you to build geometries using characters of any font you have installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tool named [SvgToXaml](https://github.com/BerndK/SvgToXaml/releases) to convert svg to xaml and you can use the resource in xaml generated by SvgToXaml.

The genereated xaml and codes use it is attached below:

```
<Button>
        <Button.Resources>
            <Geometry x:Key="iconGeometry1">F1 M22.189789,7.6945963z M0,0z M65.210466,41.41868L62.80752,41.41868 62.80752,47.625 60.823151,47.625 60.823151,41.41868 58.420205,41.41868 58.420205,39.930404 65.210466,39.930404z</Geometry>
            <Geometry x:Key="iconGeometry2">F1 M22.189789,7.6945963z M0,0z M71.969722,47.625L66.404188,47.625 66.404188,39.930404 71.969722,39.930404 71.969722,41.41868 68.378221,41.41868 68.378221,42.74676 71.711341,42.74676 71.711341,44.235037 68.378221,44.235037 68.378221,46.136723 71.969722,46.136723z</Geometry>
            <Geometry x:Key="iconGeometry3">F1 M22.189789,7.6945963z M0,0z M80.609994,47.625L78.315568,47.625 76.65676,45.092863 74.966946,47.625 72.775872,47.625 75.504379,43.74928 72.832716,39.930404 75.121974,39.930404 76.723939,42.328183 78.372412,39.930404 80.568653,39.930404 77.881487,43.671766z</Geometry>
            <DrawingGroup x:Key="iconDrawingGroup" ClipGeometry="M0,0 V7.6945963 H22.189789 V0 H0 Z">
                <DrawingGroup Opacity="1" Transform="1,0,0,1,-58.420205,-39.930404">
                    <DrawingGroup Opacity="1">
                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF000000" Geometry="{StaticResource iconGeometry1}" />
                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF000000" Geometry="{StaticResource iconGeometry2}" />
                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF000000" Geometry="{StaticResource iconGeometry3}" />
                    </DrawingGroup>
                </DrawingGroup>
            </DrawingGroup>
        </Button.Resources>
        <Image>
            <Image.Source>
                <DrawingImage Drawing="{StaticResource iconDrawingGroup}" />
            </Image.Source>
        </Image>
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SVG contains an outer group with a `transform` attribute:

```
<g
   inkscape:label="Layer 1"
   inkscape:groupmode="layer"
   id="layer1"
   transform="translate(-58.420205,-39.930404)">
```

Without using this transformation for your WPF content, the paths are simply outside the viewable area.

Resolving the transform in Inkscape is a bit tricky, because the Inkscape UI hides this group, renaming it a "layer". You need to

- make sure in Preferences that Behavior -> Transforms -> Store transformation: Optimized is selected
- open the XML editor
- select the `<svg:g>` element with `id="layer1"`
- delete the attribute `inkscape:groupmode`
- then, in the grafical UI you can ungroup the selected group (two times, to also ungroup the inner group)

This will rewrite the individual paths applying the translation so you can use them in your WPF button.